# Create Local Domain Address

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I have a webserver (running on Ubuntu Server) on my local network. It is available from outside this network as a domain name (example.com) and inside as an IP address.

**How would I map this IP to the domain example.com?** Is there a router that can do this, or do I have to set up a local DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the domain (example.com) point that domain to your public ip address. On your (inside network) go to https://www.whatismyip.com/ and you will find your public ip.

The next step you have to do is to configure your router to forward the traffic to your local ubuntu server. That is call [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). If you want to access a website from your ubuntu server then you will have to forward port 80. When you go to the router tell it to froward traffic from port 80 to the internal ip address of your ubuntu server. When you do so you will be able to access your website from anywhere in the world.

If you only want to use that domain localy for yourself then you can modify the hosts file. On ubuntu that file is located on `/etc/hosts` add the line:

192.168.0.5         somedomain.com

if you add that line to the hosts file you will be making a request to 192.168.0.5 whenever you go to somedomain.com